# hibernate mapping class

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a project which it's domain contain following classes:

```
Courier
Customer
Food
Order
Customer
PrimitiveElement
ResturantCustomerFacade
ResturantOrderFacade
```

And My database also has these tables:

```
Courier
Customer
CustomizedFood
CustomizedPrimitivePrice
FoodType
Order
PrimitiveType
ValueType
```

and the classes which hibernate makes for above tables has same name of them.
Should I use the classes which hibernate makes in my domain although I can not apply my structure of classes because of hibernate class structure.
Or I have to use my own domain classes and hibernate classes are just for databse operations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate does not **make** any classes by itself; I'm guessing you're talking about [Hibernate Tools](https://www.hibernate.org/255.html) that can be used to reverse-engineer your database schema and generate appropriate classes / mappings.

I would **strongly** advice you against having two sets of classes if you can help it; it usually brings nothing but problems. You should instead write your own mappings using mappings / classes generated by Hibernate Tools as a reference point; in majority of cases you will be able to map your domain classes to your tables with minimal or no changes (e.g. stuff like different class / table or property / column names is easily resolved via appropriate mappings; associations / inheritance is quite flexible, etc...) Here's a link to [Hibernate Annotations](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/entity.html#entity-mapping) documentation.

On a separate topic, names like `ResturantCustomerFacade` and `ResturantOrderFacade` are rather strange for domain objects. If those are indeed part of your model, consider renaming them to `RestaurantCustomer` and `RestaurantOrder`. OR, if they really are facades, they are not part of domain model and should not (can not) be mapped.

Comment: you mean I do not use reverse Engineering and make mapping myself?
which one is easier annotation or xml mapping?

Comment: As I said, you can use reverse engineering as a starting point, but you'll need to adjust generated mappings to fix your existing domain model. Annotations and XML mappings are roughly equivalent in complexity; if you're using Java 1.5 or later I suggest you go with annotations.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate should ultimately help you to [map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) *your* objects to a relational database. If you really encounter difficulties with incompatible types or legacy code, you might consider hiding them (and your hibernate-compatible implementations) behind interfaces.